# How do I handle and properly version-control a Phonegap iOS/Android project?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova

I have been investigating Phonegap as a method of deploying an app to both Android and iOS.  However, it seems like depending on what device you are programming for, there is a different set of instructions.

How do I set up something where the 'project' for both Xcode and ant are in separate directories but they both point to the same set of common assets?  And how do I version control this...what should I .hgignore and what is necessary to keep around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We generally have a www folder with the html, js, css etc for your app and a folder next to it that contains the xcode project and android project then write a simple script to copy the www code into the platform specific projects ... some of this is made more simple with tools like [github.com/brianleroux/cordova](http://github.com/brianleroux/cordova)

You could also check out [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com)